# Android Auto: "<app name> doesn't seem to be working now"

Tags: android-auto

When trying to run the application from the Android Auto car screen, from time to time, I'm getting the info:

> *app name* doesn't seem to be working now

For example:

- Spotify doesn't seem to be working now
- VRadio doesn't seem to be working now
- etc. It basically happens for each app.

Versions:

- Android: 12 SKQ1.210908.001
- Android Auto: 8.7.630264-release

Running application from the mobile helps in the most cases, but doesn't help in general.

Any ideas how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: When this happens check if your app got an update... If it updates automatically while AA is running it can have bizarre effects. I had to turn off auto updating due to issues like this and it stopped.

Comment: @acejavelin: I have automatic updates turned off.